# Trying to store a GET Requests to a DataFrame in Pandas, but getting the following error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

```
url = "https://api.defhc.com/v5/odata-v4/Hospitals?$top=500"

res = requests.get(url,headers={"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % access_token}).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

Getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret '<attribute 'dtype' of 'numpy.generic' objects>' as a data type
```

I want to be able to store the data in a DataFrame in Pandas so I can perform some analysis.

Comment: Can you post what you are receiving into `res`? If it is sensitive data, post mock data, in the same format as that of the actual data.

Comment: I do not think you will receive answers if you do not provide at least some mockup data.